# Is uncountable summation the same as integration with the counting measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a set (possible uncountable) and $\phi:A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. By uncountable summation $\sum_A \phi (a)$, I mean that the sums over finite subsets of $A$, i.e., $s_F = \sum_F \phi (a)$ where $F\subseteq A$ is finite, converge as a net (with inclusion as its partial order).

We can also define a counting measure $\mu$ on $A$. Then is it true that $\phi \in l^p(A) \Leftrightarrow \phi \in L^p(\delta)$. More specifically, is it true that
$$
\sum_A |\phi(a)|^p =\int |\phi|^p d\mu,  \quad p\in [1,\infty)
$$

EDIT: update via comments: Dirac measure $\rightarrow$ counting measure

Comment: Not the [Dirac (delta) measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure), but the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure), i.e., $\mu\colon\mathcal{P}(A)\to[0,\infty]$, $\mu(B)=\#B$ if $B\subseteq A$ finite, $\infty$ if infinite.

Comment: Both your summation and integrating with counting measure are equivalent  to there only being countably many non-zero values and the series made from these converging absolutely